# grab values and column names based on row values (multiple values in cell)

Tags: pandas, row, multiple-columns, cell

I have this df

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'R': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4', 4: '5', 5: '6', 6: '7'},\
                    'a': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 3.0, 4: 3.0, 5: 2.0, 6: 3.0},\
                    'b': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 2.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 3.0},\
                    'c': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 2.0, 5: -2.0, 6: -2.0}, \
                    'd': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 2.0, 6: -1.0},\
                    'e': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 2.0, 6: -2.0}, \
                    'f': {0: -1.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: -2.0, 5: -1.0, 6: 2.0},\
                    'g': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 1.5, 4: 2.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 2.0}, \
                    'h': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 2.0, 5: 1.0, 6: 3.0}, \
                    'i': {0: 0.0, 1: -1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: -3.0, 6: 3.0}, \
                    'j': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 2.0, 5: -1.0, 6: -1.0}, \
                    'k': {0: 62, 1: 166, 2: 139, 3: 60, 4: 93, 5: 17, 6: 5}} )
```

which gives us

```
    R    a    b    c     d    e    f     g    h     i    j    k
0   1   1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0  -1.0  1.0  0.0   0.0  1.0  62
1   2   1.0  1.0  2.0   2.0  2.0   0.0  1.0  0.0  -1.0  1.0  166
2   3   2.0  1.0  2.0   1.0  2.0   0.0  2.0  1.0   0.0  1.0  139
3   4   3.0  2.0  2.0   0.0  1.0   0.0  1.5  2.0   0.0  1.0  60
4   5   3.0  2.0  2.0   1.0  1.0  -2.0  2.0  2.0   0.0  2.0  93
5   6   2.0  0.0 -2.0   2.0  2.0  -1.0  0.0  1.0  -3.0  -1.0 17
6   7   3.0  3.0 -2.0  -1.0  -2.0  2.0  2.0  3.0   3.0  -1.0  5
```

I need 2 new columns

df['an']= displays **column name** of each column where the current raw had negative value

df['nv']= displays **negative values** of each column where the current raw had negative value

Desired output

```
    R    a    b    c     d    e    f     g    h     i    j    k    an        nv   
0   1   1.0  1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0  -1.0  1.0  0.0   0.0  1.0  62   'f'        -1 
1   2   1.0  1.0  2.0   2.0  2.0   0.0  1.0  0.0  -1.0  1.0  166  'i'        -1
2   3   2.0  1.0  2.0   1.0  2.0   0.0  2.0  1.0   0.0  1.0  139  '-'        -
3   4   3.0  2.0  2.0   0.0  1.0   0.0  1.5  2.0   0.0  1.0  60   '-'        - 
4   5   3.0  2.0  2.0   1.0  1.0  -2.0  2.0  2.0   0.0  2.0  93   'f'        -2
5   6   2.0  0.0 -2.0   2.0  2.0  -1.0  0.0  1.0  -3.0  -1.0 17   'c,f,i,j' [-2,-1,-3,-1]
6   7   3.0  3.0 -2.0  -1.0  -2.0  2.0  2.0  3.0   3.0  -1.0  5   'c,d,e,j' [-2,-1,-2,-1]
```

I tried multiple code options, such as np.where or np.select, but I could not mmake it work.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use comparison and boolean indexing per row, save the intermediate variable using assignment expression, and create a Series:

```
df.join(df.drop(columns='R')
          .apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'an': ','.join((S:=s[s.lt(0)]).index),
                                      'nv': list(S)}), axis=1)
       )
```

Or using a custom function:

```
def f(s):
    S = s[s.lt(0)]
    return pd.Series({'an': ','.join(S.index),
                      'nv': list(S)})

df.join(df.drop(columns='R').apply(f, axis=1))
```

output:

```
   R    a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j    k       an                        nv
0  1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0 -1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0   62        f                    [-1.0]
1  2  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  0.0  1.0  0.0 -1.0  1.0  166        i                    [-1.0]
2  3  2.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  0.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  139                                 []
3  4  3.0  2.0  2.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.5  2.0  0.0  1.0   60                                 []
4  5  3.0  2.0  2.0  1.0  1.0 -2.0  2.0  2.0  0.0  2.0   93        f                    [-2.0]
5  6  2.0  0.0 -2.0  2.0  2.0 -1.0  0.0  1.0 -3.0 -1.0   17  c,f,i,j  [-2.0, -1.0, -3.0, -1.0]
6  7  3.0  3.0 -2.0 -1.0 -2.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  3.0 -1.0    5  c,d,e,j  [-2.0, -1.0, -2.0, -1.0]
```

Comment: @josepmaria can you give more details? Have you tested on the provided sample? Works fine for me